Какой формат использовать для отображения анимации из блендера в браузере Safari?
В блендере создал анимацию на 10сек-240фреймов. Затем зарендерил в WebM формат чтобы сохранить качество картинки и минимизировать вес. Но этот формат не поддерживается браузером Safari. Сделать GIF не могу так как она будет шакально выглядеть и весить 8мб+. Сделать mp4 версию тоже не могу
из-за отсутствия альфа канала.
Так же что важно я не могу использовать css свойство mix-blendmode так как оно изменяет саму анимацию. Отрендерить со статичным фоном тоже не подойдет так как фон анимированный, засинхронить с анимацией тоже не выйдет из-за логика сайта.
Подскажите как решить этот трабл

Думаю, что для начала вам нужно попробовать сделать покадровую css-анимацию PNG. Всё конечно сильно зависит от первоначального общего веса всех кадров вместе взятых, но попробовать точно стоит. Второй этап экспериментов, если не срастётся с первым — <canvas>. Впрочем можете, почитать, словно для вас написанную, свежую статью... может подберёте другое решение.

Спасибо за статью, очень полезная но к сожалению решение конкретно моей проблемы в ней нет

Если ваша проблема в том, что Safari во всём виноват, то пишите в соответствующие саппорты и спрашивайте: "сколько можно терпеть?", а если вам нужно помощь в решении, то... Либо вы невнимательно читаете, либо не читаете, либо ленитесь думать. Конкретно в той статье, способ о котором я говорил, называется — секвенция. Не забыли они и o canvas.

секвенция из 240 изображений будет весить 10+мб и в плохом качестве. У меня сложная анимация, канвас тут не спасет. Лотти тоже не подходит, файл вышел в 4-5мб с хорошим качеством, но лотти как-то странно отрабатывает, он тупо останавливает весь сайт чтобы полностью загрузиться. У меня есть прелоудер но лотти даже прелоудер останавливает... В общем я хз что с этим делать

В  mp4/h264 сожми и положи в тег  с параметрами: мутед, автоплей, репит.

h.264 не поддерживает альфа канал

Не заметил. Извиняюсь)

@AlimKosaev а если VP8 или VP9?

та же история.
я вроде нашел решение, использую лотти анимации но теперь трабл другой, при импорте лотти анимации в react по инструкции от сервиса, у меня тупо останавливается сайт до того момента пока анимация не запустится. Я пробовал ее в саспенс закидывать, и асинхронно брал данные с их json файла, ничего не помогло. Не одно так другое как говорится....
